# The App I deployed on Heroku sometime shows the page with "There is nothing here yet"

Tags: heroku

I have deployed an App on Heroku, everything just work properly. However, there is one problem, which I still couldn't find out the possible reason after a three days of research:

Here is the problem, sometime when I open my App, they just show me this page with "There is nothing here yet" which means that there is no application deployed here:
[Image of this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPqWk.png)

However, after refresh the page, everything would just work properly:
[works again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApxqK.png)

I am sure that I have successfully deployed the app and I didn't configure anything related to DNS or domain name, as a result I don't even know where should I start debugging. Does anyone ran into same problem too? Thanks !